# mongod is not saving dbpath

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up mongodb on an Ubuntu server.
But MongoDB seems to not saving the dbpath I give.
Neither as

```
mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb/data/db
```

nor as a config file

```
mongod -f ~/etc/mongod.conf
```

> ---
>
> ERROR: dbpath (~/mongodb/data/db) does not exist.
>    Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
>    See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
>
> ---

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 21154
  http:
    enabled: true
security:
  authorization: enabled
storage:
  dbPath: "~/mongodb/data/db"
  smallFiles: true
```

- ~/etc/mongod.conf

Mongo has full permission to those directories.
After closing the connection when mongo is waiting for on on 27017, he forgets the dbPath again.

Hope somebody could finally help, and hope I'm not getting something completely wrong since I'm new to Ubuntu & setting up mongodb.

Cheers.

Comment: are you sure you have created ~/mongodb/data/db? Because error tells that this directory doesn't exists.(You need to create this directory manually, mongo will not create)

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Yes, all directories exist and have full permission (through chmod 777)

Comment: Can you try: mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: The tilde(`~`) to mean `$HOME` is a shell expansion, so it isn't expected to work in a config file, try using the full path.

Answer (score 0):

The command should be

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
mongod --dbpath /etc/mongodb/data/db
```

and not

`mongod --config ~/etc/mongodb.conf
 mongod --dbpath ~/mongodb/data/db`

and as said by @joe
The **tilde(~**) to mean `$HOME` is a shell expansion, so it isn't expected to work in a config file, try using the full path

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
MongoDB is running under a daemon on my server and the run-script of the daemon was just wrong.
It didn't have the right parameters. So I changed the script so the mongod.conf is called by the daemon and changed the path to the absolute path.